# graph representation tool for huge data with specific features

Tags: javafx, graph, bigdata, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm building a **JavaFX** app and I want to display interactive graph of my huge data in it. something like placing cytoscape in **javaFX** app and working with graph inside of my app. my node may be up to 30000 nodes at max but usually its about 200 nodes after filtering nodes.

key features (sorted by importance):

1. generating graph with best layout and good looking with good performance and low overlapping (same as cytoscape)
2. selection some nodes and mark them (same as ctrl+L in cytoscape)
3. selecting neighbours of some nodes
4. building new graph from number 3
5. filtering graph base on weights, number of edges and ...
6. hiding and showing some selected edges and nodes
7. capturing image of built graph

Additional features :

1. zoom in zoom out
2. node tagging
3. multi color nodes and edges
4. Changing width of edges base on weight
5. Changing color of specific nodes and edges without rebuilding graph
6. Directed edge support

I have tested cytoscape.js but couldnt use it in javaFX browser. im testing WebVowl now. is anything better than these for my purpose ? if you suggest something that it cant be placed in javaFX app directly, please show how I do it. 
Thanks

Comment: Tool/library recommendation questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: its about recommending tools that can combine with javaFX. or helping to use a library with specific features

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could use Cytoscape as the data model, and build a JavaFX renderer around it.  I've wanted to do this, but it's not in roadmap associated with our funding.

I've done a few JavaFX projects that might be good starting points, but they don't integrate directly with Cytoscape, which has a richer model of subnetworks, groups, etc.

https://github.com/AdamStuart/appFX/tree/master2/src/main/java/diagrams

one of which is based on a great example from TESIS DYNAware GmbH.

As you realize, the key issue is filtering down the network before trying to visualize it.  The number of edges associated with 30000 nodes will bog down most any system, if you try to build something interactive.